# Frontpage slideshow not showing

Tags: views

Here are the steps that I have taken:

1. Created a content type of "slide" with the following fields
   Title
   Body
   Link
   Image
2. Created 3 slides with "slide" content type.
3. Created a new view named "slideshow" using Views Slideshow (slideshow). The preview correctly displayed the slideshow.
4. Added the block "slideshow" in the theme's block "Featured"
5. Configured the block to show only slide content.
6. Saved the block.
7. Cleared the registry by typing "drush cr". Cleared.
8. Clicked Firefox refresh button.
9. Clicked the "Home". Only the "Welcome Text .." displayed. No slideshow.
10. Rechecked Views Slideshow to ensure that it is correctly displayed.
11. Update mariadb.
12. Refreshed. Still no slideshow.

Have I missed something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

M A Sani

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what you mean by "Configured the block to show only slide content."?

This seems off to me as you would instead configure the VIEW to only show slide content. When it comes down to block configuration, those settings are for *visibility* aka what urls and/or types of pages that block region will show that block.

If you wanted the block to be on the homepage only, you would add `<front>` in the *Pages* tab of the block visibility settings.

If you did indeed "configure the block to only show on slide content", then you told Drupal to show the block when you are actually viewing a slide node page aka "node/xx" where xx is a node id of a slide.